# charpits equations to solve $u_x u_y=1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

$u_x u_y=1$ with initial data $u=0$ and $x+y=1$

Parametrise with $x=s$ and $y=1-s$

diffeq can be written as $F(p,q) = pq - 1 = 0$

Charpits equations give:
$dx/dt = q$,
$dy/dt = p$,
$dp/dt = 0$,
$dq/dt = 0$,
$du/dt = 2pq$

Solving these we get $p=p_0(s)$ and $q=q_0(s)$ 
and $x = q_0(s)t + x_0 = q_0(s)t + s $
and $y = p_0(s)t + y_0 = p_0(s)t + 1-s $
and $u = 2p_0(s)q_0(s)t$

$F(p_0,q_0) = 0 $ implies that $p_0q_0 = 1$ 
and $du_0(s)/ds = p_0(dx_0/ds)+ q_0(dy_0/ds)$ implies $p_0 = q_0$

As a result $p_0 = q_0 = -1$ or $1 $ and so $u=2t$

How do i then go about stating where each solution exists and further proving that for a real solution to exist, $[du_0(s) / ds ]^2 \geq 4 [dx_0(s)/ds][dy_0(s)/ds]$

Answer (score 2):

For general initial conditions $z_0(s)=u(x_0(s),y_0(s))$ you get the system of equations 
$$
p_0(s)q_0(s)=1\\
p_0(s)\dot x_0(s)+q_0(s)\dot y_0(s)=\dot z_0(s)
$$
which looks almost like the Viete's equations for a quadratic equation. Multiply the first equation with $\dot x_0\dot y_0$ to get that $p_0(s)\dot x_0(s)$ and $q_0(s)\dot y_0(s)$ are the root pair of
$$
r^2-\dot z_0\cdot r + \dot x_0\dot y_0=0.
$$
Now check the discriminant for a condition to get real solutions.

Comment: Cheers, ill try that. Is the rest of my answer correct?

Comment: Yes, and as $0>-1$, the condition is satisfied.

Comment: Hi in struggling to see how you got the equation involving r^2, how did you come to that part

Comment: By Viete. $(r-r_1)(r-r_2)=r^2-(r_1+r_2)r+r_1r_2$.